# Is eq always called in scala ==?

Tags: scala

I have implemented a set wrapper using a canonical map (in scala). Now, when redefining the equals (and hashCode) I want the collections that contain my set wrapper to use reference equality, i.e. "eq". However, the collection that I use for the canonical map should use the real "equals". I've come up with the following solution:

```
  override def equals(obj: Any) =
  obj match {
    case o: SetWrapper => (o eq this) || o.set == this.set
    case _ => false
  }
```

My question is, do I really need this?

```
(o eq this) || o.set == this.set
```

or is it enough to use this?

```
  override def equals(obj: Any) =
  obj match {
    case o: SetWrapper => o.set == this.set
    case _ => false
  }
```

I'm guessing that the library automatically does the "eq" before calling the equals (when using ==), but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` calls `equals`, with a proper handling of `null` values. You have to call `eq` yourself if you want that optimization.